# Relative path in serenity properties file

Tags: properties-file, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I want to provide a relative path in `serenity.properties` file. So that my project is OS independent.

When I am trying:

```
chrome_preferences.download.default_directory = /target
```

it is failing, means chrome's default directory doesn't change but when I give full path like this

```
chrome_preferences.download.default_directory = D:\\automation-practice-tests\\target
```

it works perfectly fine, but if I choose to use absolute path it will not remain OS independent.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you specify just `target`? A leading `/` normally indicates the root of the filesystem.

Comment: It doesn't take `target`. It keeps on download file in chromes default directory i.e. Downloads folder. Does specifying only `target` worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

I know is a little late, but this is how I resolved the problem:

```
chrome_preferences.download.default_directory=${user.dir}\\src\\test\\resources\\files\\downloads
```

In your case

```
chrome_preferences.download.default_directory = ${user.dir}\\target
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my Mac and I am able to download the file

```
chrome.preferences.download.default_directory="${user.dir}\\target"
chrome.preferences.profile.default_content_settings.popupsy=0
chrome_preferences.pdfjs.disabled=true
```